# Need help translating a MYSQL DB Sql Query into a Jpql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, wildfly, jpql

I have 3 entities - usergroup, user, usergroupmemberships. usergroupmemberships has a 1 to 1 to both user and usergroup. im trying to get a users groups with his id

The following Query works in my DB:

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserGroup g 
JOIN UserGroupMembership ON 
UserGroupMembership.usergroup_id = g.id 
WHERE UserGroupMembership.user_id = 868
```

Wildfly:

the same as a Java REST POST that uses a query from my entitymanager doesnt with a nullpointerexception

```
SELECT g 
FROM UserGroup g 
JOIN UserGroupMembership 
ON UserGroupMembership.usergroup = g.id 
WHERE UserGroupMembership.user = :id
```

How do i write this correctly?

Tried different ways to write the query and tried writing user_id
im on wildfly and java ee

```
public List<UserGroup> findUserGroupbyUser(long id) {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT g FROM UserGroup g JOIN 
    UserGroupMembership ON UserGroupMembership.usergroup = g WHERE 
    UserGroupMembership.user.id = :id", UserGroup.class).setParameter("id", 
id).getResultList();
}

@Entity
public class UserGroupMembership {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private UserGroup usergroup;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private User user;
```

expected result is 1 entry

Comment: Here's the documentation on HQL/JPQL. It has a section on joins. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql. Don't try random things. Learn the language by reading the documentation. It's much more effective that way. BTW, Your OneToOne should be ManyToOne, since I guess that there are more than one user per group, and that a user can belong to several groups.

Comment: should it really be a ManyToOne? Im using this help class to evade having to use FetchType.Eager or a huge join fetch statement as wildflys hibernate configuration seems really tricky there to me to not endlessly load new resources in a loop. i would just have a table with a list of objects with 1 user and 1 usergroup and out of this i could filter my result?

Comment: The Doku has a similar example that does it this way: return em.createQuery("SELECT g FROM UserGroup g JOIN UserGroupMembership ugm WHERE ugm.user = :id", UserGroup.class).setParameter("id", em.find(User.class, id)).getResultList();

returns the error

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where usergroupm1_.user_id=868' at line 1